# Character blocking when walking on cube edges

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I have my character walking on a ground made of cube. (scale 1,1,1). There is no space between them.  Also, I have a `RigidBody` with 15 drag and I'm moving with `AddForce`.

When I walk, my character sometimes block when trying to pass over the place where the 2 box meet. Like if my player collider was hitting the collider under him. Any fix for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floor is made up of tiles with their own box colliders. Pushable item gets stuck on the "seams"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146898/floor-is-made-up-of-tiles-with-their-own-box-colliders-pushable-item-gets-stuck)

Answer (score 1):

Edit-> Project Setting-> physics-> Default Contact Offset to 0.0001 made it for me